# What is a Christmas Word™? (also: Connect the Clues!)

Tags: pattern, word-property, seasonal

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

***'Tis the season ....***

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Christmas Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Christmas Words™ | Not Christmas Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DO | LO |
| BE | LET |
| GOD | LAY |
| HAS | ALL |
| JOY | OLD |
| GORY | BLOODY |
| RIFE | VOID |
| SEAS | CALM |
| WORD | LETTER |
| CAUSE | EFFECT |
| FIGHT | BATTLE |
| FURRY | WOOLLY |
| SEDGE | LEDGE |
| CATTER | CHATTER |
| MIKING | FILMING |
| NESTED | SNUGGLED |
| SEEPING | OOZING |
| REVERIES | DAYDREAMS |
| DOCTORESS | DEFIER |
| PHENOMENA | MIRACLE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Christmas Words™,Not Christmas Words™
DO,LO
BE,LET
GOD,LAY
HAS,ALL
JOY,OLD
GORY,BLOODY
RIFE,VOID
SEAS,CALM
WORD,LETTER
CAUSE,EFFECT
FIGHT,BATTLE
FURRY,WOOLLY
SEDGE,LEDGE
CATTER,CHATTER
MIKING,FILMING
NESTED,SNUGGLED
SEEPING,OOZING
REVERIES,DAYDREAMS
DOCTORESS,DEFIER
PHENOMENA,MIRACLE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Christmas Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Christmas Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

---

## Connect the Clues

**Is *MANGER* a Christmas Word™?**
Please explain your answer!

Comment: It seems as if Markdown fails if an apostrophe is encountered...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Christmas Words

> can have Ls inserted to make Christmas-related words. (Specifically, songs from carols? I think?)

Specifically...

> DOLL, BELL, GOLD, HALLS, JOLLY, GLORY, RIFLE, SEALS, WORLD, CLAUSE, FLIGHT, FLURRY, SLEDGE, CLATTER, MILKING, NESTLED, SLEEPING, REVELRIES, DOCTORLESS, PHENOMENAL

Comment: (Not sure about the penultimate one.)

Comment: So far so good. But unless, among other things, you know some gun related Christms tune I'm unaware of, they're not from carols.  What about ***MANGER***?

Answer (score 7):

Christmas Words

> Have no L (noel), but can have one (or more; specifically: two, consecutive) inserted or appended to become a new word

so MANGER

> is indeed a Christmas word, because we can insert an L to make it MANGLER

---

**Edit:** This is wrong (though it seems to be close, so I'll leave it here) because DEFIER is a Not Christmas Word™